# Mi diseño en Java Swing no se ve igual al ejecutar el programa

Tags: java, java-swing, look-and-feel

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para la escuela y tengo un problema con cómo se muestra el diseño al final, son pequeños errores visuales, pero que aún así no sé como solucionarlo.
Así se debería ver:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y así es como se ve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Creo que no tiene que ver con el look and feel porque ya probé en cambiar a Windows y sí se soluciona, pero al hacerlo se mostraban errores en el textArea, y personalmente me gusta más el estilo de Nimbus:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se si es la tontera que domina mi cerebro, pero no veo cual sería el problema... (aparte de no usar "nimbus").

Comment: Creo que no me explique bien, si te das cuenta en la primera imagen sale todo normal, pero al momento de ejecutar el programa se distorsiona un poco como la segunda imagen muestra, los panels se mueven un poco y no se a que se debe o como solucionar eso. Hallé una forma que es cambiar el look&feel de nimbus a windows, pero al hacer eso la info del TextArea se mueve mucho (tercera imagen), no sale todo alineado como debería (segunda imagen).

Comment: De hecho, el estilo de Nimbus es el mismo que estás mostrando en la segunda imagen. Y está en [los tutoriales de Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html). Lo de "probé en cambiar a Windows y sí se soluciona": claro, porque está tomando el LAF (_Look And Feel_) del sistema operativo. De hecho, si probás entre Windows 10, Windows 8 y Windows 7, en cada uno de tales SO se verá distinto :)

Comment: ¿Cuáles son los "errores en el TextArea"?

Answer (score 0):

Ahora si veo los "detalles" que mencionas, para estar seguro, debería ver tu código, pero para empezar, tienes un problema por el que pasé recientemente, tu IGU, tiene una altura y anchos fijos, y los elementos dentro de ella, tienen una relación directa con estos, esto hace que dependa de cada SO, lo que se ve, porqué?, porque cada SO, tiene margenes distintos, y eso cambia la posición de los elementos.
Lo puedes solucionar así:

```
    // instancias un objeto Insets, que contendrá los margenes que usa el SO. 
  Insets screenInsets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
          .getScreenInsets( getGraphicsConfiguration() );

    // le pides al SO. los mismos
  screenInsets = getInsets();

    // los cargas en sus respectivas variables
  int altoBarra = screenInsets.top;
  int altoPiso = screenInsets.bottom;
  int anchoBorde = screenInsets.left;

    // seteas tu "Frame"
  int altoFrame = 540 + altoBarra + altoPiso; // 508
  int anchoFrame = 230 + anchoBorde * 2;  // 229
  setBounds( x, y, anchoFrame, altoFrame );  // 532
```

espero que te ayude a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: ¿En que parte exactamente debería colocarlo?, disculpa la pregunta

Comment: el **setBounds( x, y, anchoFrame, altoFrame );** es el seteo de tu IGU, puede que lo tengas como **frame.setBounds( x, y, anchoFrame, altoFrame );**, para darle las medidas exactas, debes tener en cuenta los valores que obtienes con **Insets**, osea, si quieres que tu frame tenga una altura de "500", pones **frame.setBounds( x, y, anchoFrame, 500 + altoBara + altoPiso );**, esto obviamente es en el constructor de tu IGU.